# How to display HTML tags as plain text in ExtJS Preview Plugin's Content field

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am using a Preview Plugin in ext js View Config for Grid Panel. When the value has HTML tags e.g:`<b> sample </b>` EXT JS is rendering the word "sample" in bold. Can any one please help me to display the text as it is, i.e. `<b> sample </b>` instead of the word sample in Bold letters. Setting HTMLEncode to true and setting the Renderer as HTML Encode is working for display fields, but not working in the Content field of Preview Plugin. Even the Heading field of Preview plugin is displaying HTML as plain text, but I am having problem with Content field. Is there any other attribute that I can use?

Thanks in advance for your time and effort.

Vasavi.

Comment: Can you find answer??